# FluentAssertions Equivalency Comparison Behavior and IMemberInfo

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I am using FluentAssertions (v6.2.0) to test API's that return table-like data. I want to change comparison behavior for one of the field, and tried to use method described in [documentation](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/#equivalency-comparison-behavior).

```
orderDto.Should().BeEquivalentTo(order, options => options
    .Using<DateTime>(ctx => ctx.Subject.Should().BeCloseTo(ctx.Expectation, 1.Seconds()))
    .When(info => info.Name == "Date"));
```

The issue is that `IMemberInfo` class that `When` extension method is expecting doesn't have `Name` property, it has property called `Path`. Was `Name` replaced by `Path` and this is a typo in documentation, or do I need to import another namespace to use `Name` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick look at the [FluentAssertions source code](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions), I'm seeing that the `info` argument is of type `IObjectInfo` and it has a `Path` property. A quick test with this code shows the `Path` property working as you would expect:

```
void Main()
{
    var orderDto = new OrderDto { Date = DateTime.Now };
    var order = new Order { Date = DateTime.Now };
    //var order = new Order { Date = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)) };

    orderDto.Should().BeEquivalentTo(order, options => options
        .Using<DateTime>(ctx => ctx.Subject.Should().BeCloseTo(ctx.Expectation, 1.Seconds()))
        .When(info => info.Path == "Date"));
}

class OrderDto {
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

class Order
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

In fact, the FluentAssertions test for that code also uses path. See https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/blob/master/Tests/FluentAssertions.Specs/Equivalency/ExtensibilityRelatedEquivalencySpecs.cs#L394

There is also an `IMethodInfo` interface with both `Name` and `Path` properties. However, that is used by the `Include*` and `Exclude*` methods.

So it appears to be a documentation bug.

Comment: Thank you, Jack! I used `Path` in my code. This question was more of "Documentation typo" report for the FluentAssertions author, because it was not really a bug, and Github issue creation template for FluentAssertions stated to ask questions like this on SO, and not on Github.

Comment: Fixed the docs.